# How to compile ts files into js into particular directories

Tags: typescript, tsc, lerna

I trying to compile typescript files with tsc command and  use and lernajs to manage multi-package repositories.
My directory structure is as follows:

```
Project
-Packages
--Module1
---Src
----file1.ts
--package.json
--Module2
---Src
----file2.ts
--package.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
learna.json
```

After compilation the result directory structure should be as follows (Build directory generated):

```
Project
-Packages
--Module1
---Build
----file1.js
---Src
----file1.ts
--package.json
--Module2
---Build
----file2.js
---Src
----file2.ts
--package.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
learna.json
```

As I said I am using tsc with lerna. I have already tried many options, however, the Build directory was created outside the module directories.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with a single TypeScript project.  You'll need to create a separate `tsconfig.json` file for each package that specifies the desired `outDir`.  You can use [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) to set things up so you can compile all the packages with a single `tsc -b` command.